# How can I calculate how much my desktop PC costs to run for an hour?

Tags: output, computers, efficiency, cost, pc

*I was torn on whether to post this to here or Math.SE, so feel free to move it as appropriate.*

I recently got hold of a power usage monitor in order to calculate how much my PC costs to run a given task for an hour, but before I do so, I want to find out how to do the calculation "on paper", and use the power usage monitor to determine just how accurate it is.

That being said, this question essentially has two parts to it.

Firstly, the PSU on my PC has a max output of 550W, but I've been advised that it's likely to use much less than that even when running. To that end, is CPU usage in the Windows Task Manager a reliable enough metric to use for this purpose?

In other words, ***if my CPU is consistently showing 25% (or 100%) of usage consistently for carrying out a specific task, can I assume that 25% (or 100%) of 550W is a good starting point for the sake of calculating cost?***

Secondly, ***what is the calculation to determine the cost of running a PC for a single hour?***

I have somewhere to start in that I know that the formula:

## Power usage (in watts) * hours of usage / 1000 * cost per kWh

...can be used to determine the cost of running a PC for the given amount of hours.

Knowing that, is finding out the cost for a single hour as simple as omitting the hours of usage from the formula, like so:

## Power usage (in watts) / 1000 * cost per kWh

...or is it more complicated than that?

These might seem stupid questions, but my maths skills especially are really lacking, and I've been frustrating myself over the last few days trying to work it out, so I'd appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: **Wattage**, also known as **power**. Knowledge is wattage, what.

Comment: Power's a very broad term though, isn't it? I wanted to make it unambiguous. Maybe power usage would be a good alternative, though even that doesn't make it clear it needs to be in watts.

Comment: In electronics and physics in general, the term power has a clear and unambiguous meaning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(physics)

Comment: Wattage is a word that is recognized and in the dictionary. But so is the word shenanigan. -- There was some other question where a user thought that wattage was not a word, and he got really upset when he realized that he was wrong. And I share that anger with him. Henceforth I shall eradicate all the wattage sayers!

Comment: @Dampmaskin So would it be relevant here, given that the physics definition is `watts / time` and we're just looking to use watts?

Comment: @HarrySvensson Was that user you? ;)

Comment: The physics definition of a watt is one Joule per second, not one Watt per second. The W/s quantity that you refer to seems pretty obscure, and would refer to a change in power over time, akin to accelleration being a change in velocity over time. Edit: It seems you have been confused by the definiton of horsepower. The W in that particular formula refers to work, not watts. Watt is a unit of measurement. Work, like power, is a quantity. This type of formulas contain quantities, not units.

Comment: Sorry no, I was referring to the physics definition of/equation for power, as indicated in the Wiki article you linked to. There it gives power as being watt / time.

Comment: Ah, so that W is referring to work? I see.

Comment: I decided to replace wattage with "power usage (in watts)". While everyone on this SE site might understand the definition of "power", I know that it'd be ambiguous to a non-engineer/physics person like me, and I want to make it clear to anyone that comes across the question via a search engine.

Comment: I've looked for the question to find where the person was upset to prove that it wasn't me. But it appears that the question got deleted... and instead I found a gazillion amount of questions using the word wattage. So I guess it's not worth my time to eradicate anyone.

Answer (score 3):

No, your Windows Task Manager will give a really really bad estimate of how much power your computer currently consumes. Because, it will show you how "busy" a processor is. Moving memory around takes different amount of power than to calculate things.

There's different ways to make a processor busy, or look busy. And they all take different amount of power.

The greatest power hog in your computer is probably the GPU, which as far as I know you can't really see in the Windows Task manager.

And your equations are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to your second question. The cost for one hour just removes the "hours" term from the formula.

Regarding the first part, there's no easy way to calculate it from stats like CPU usage. Even if you had an accurate enough log of that and integrate it over time to get your mean value, there's far more energy being consumed and radiated as heat. Remember, what you want is the energy consumed. Everything is less than 100% efficient, radiating the unused energy as heat. If your PSU for instance is 95% efficient, then at 100W consumed, 95W is going to the rest of the PC and 5W is going as heat.

Everything is doing that. The CPU, the chipset, the graphics card (major user there), the fans, the drives, the go-faster LEDs, *even the cables* are dropping some volts and radiating it as heat.

The only way to be sure about this is a good quality power monitor at the input. Any attempt at a paper calculation will have so many unknowns as to be effectively useless.

Comment: I thought I'd mentioned it in the post, but I was considering using 200W as a calculation, as I was advised my computer is more likely to be using something along those lines. Would you say that would be just as inaccurate?

Comment: @Hashim You are trying to determine the accuracy of a device by comparing it to a calculation that, as all of the above answers show, is very inaccurate.  Assuming the PC power consumption is fixed at some value, e.g. 200 watts, without any basis, is not going to give you any useful information. If you want to verify the accuracy of your power monitor, you are going to need equipment with much more accuracy than can be achieved by using dubious estimates with a PC.

Comment: When I say I want to verify the accuracy of my usage monitor, it isn't for scientific purposes - purely for the sake of my own curiosity, as some fun. Would using 200W as a base not even be sufficient for that purpose?

Comment: You can probably have some fun with it. Whether or not it will quell your curiosity is entirely up to you.

Comment: Hashim, no you're not even going to get a ballpark figure. A guess is a guess and nothing more. One thing you can do; if you've got a "smart" electric meter with a display, switch off everything else in the house and see what it says. That's the figure the power company use to calculate your bill, so it will be pretty accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Your formulas are correct but your initial assumption is not. It is highly unlikely that the total power consumption of your PC can be correlated with the CPU usage as reported by Windows. First, as you seem to be already aware, the power output capability of the PSU will always be more than the PC is actually using.  Also, even if it was, you neglected the efficiency of the PSU.  If it is generating 550 watts, it will be drawing significantly more from the AC line since it is not 100% efficient. Also the fan is always drawing power that is not part of the 550 watts. You are better off relying on your power usage monitor to get a good value for the PC power consumption.  The monitor will also be able to integrate the power usage over time much more accurately than you ever could using the CPU usage value.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental mistake in the formulation of this question is in your assumption that 550W PSU has something to do with actual power consumption. It is not.

The actual power consumption is defined by **"thermal envelope"** of your CPU, plus whatever the similar envelope of your videocard is. If the thermal envelope of your CPU is, say, 90W, the **system won't let it go above**, by various automated throttling mechanisms. The power delivery system will have certain losses, safe to assume 80% efficiency, so the CPU block will consume about 112W maximum.

I can't speak of crazy gaming machines, but all my desktop PCs (and I have nearly a dozen of them) rarely consume more than 180W, even an old i7-920 machine with 130W envelop and GeForce GTX 950. Some ITX boxes with i3 processors take 30-40W from AC, some bigger ones take 90 - 130 W. Monitors take 30 - 90 watts.

As you said, the easiest way is to get a power meter (even the cheapest one, ["Kill-A-Watt"](http://www.homedepot.com/p/P3-International-Kill-A-Watt-EZ-Meter-P4460/202196388)), and measure the actual consumption over time and use pattern. It can even calculate the overall cost (assuming 10c/kWh). Mathematics has very little to do with the actual results.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part:

No, you can't make a function based on CPU usage with any kind of accuracy. Along with the CPU, a good deal of the total power consumption will be based on GPU activity in your graphics adapter. Try loading a game and watch your power monitor.

Disk I/O will affect power too, depending on your disk technology.

And fan controls of the chassis fans, GPU, and CPU fans can't be calculated solely on the processing usage reported by Windows.

If you include your monitor in the calculation, you'll find power usage change depending on the colors and brightness of the screen!

Comment: Interesting. So what you seem to be saying is that Task Manager's CPU Usage is *only* a measure of CPU usage, and nothing else?

Comment: @Hashim Yes, that's right. You may be able to get some free software for motherboard monitoring, which may be able to provide you with power utilization at the component level. Check with your motherboard manufacturer first. Many such tools can provide you with memory voltages, fan speeds, thermals, etc... possibly mb power consumptions.

Comment: There are PSUs on the market that monitor their own power delivery and report it via a USB connection, but that of course requires throwing money at the problem.